# Mimic curl request with jQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, curl

How can I properly translate this curl request into a jquery `$.ajax()` call?

Here is the curl request:

`curl https://<api token>:@api.inboxapp.com/n/<namespace id>/threads?tag=unread`

Here is my attempt at translating it that results in an authorised error:

```
$.ajax({    
    url: 'https://api.inboxapp.com/n/'+namespaceResults['id']+'/threads?tag=unread',
    dataType: 'json',
    method: 'GET',
    success: function(threadsResults){
        console.log(threadsResults);
    }
});
```

I don't know where to put the api token. I tried this, but got the same error:

```
$.ajax({    
    url: 'https://api.inboxapp.com/n/'+namespaceResults['id']+'/threads?tag=unread',
    dataType: 'json',
    method: 'GET',
    data:{
        'api_token':apiToken
    },
    success: function(threadsResults){
        console.log(threadsResults);
    }
});
```

My main issue is figuring out how to pass the apiToken authentication header properly. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to stringify the data. And contenttype is sometimes needed

```
$.ajax({    
url: 'https://api.inboxapp.com/n/'+namespaceResults['id']+'/threads?tag=unread',
dataType: 'json',
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
method: 'GET',
data: JSON.stringify( {
    'api_token':apiToken
}),
success: function(threadsResults){
    console.log(threadsResults);
}
});
```

according to inbox.app, though, api token should be sent as username:

```
$.ajax({    
url: 'https://api.inboxapp.com/n/'+namespaceResults['id']+'/threads?tag=unread',
dataType: 'json',
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
method: 'GET',
username: apiToken,
success: function(threadsResults){
    console.log(threadsResults);
}
});
```

Comment: how did you know they key for the apiToken was api_token? was that from the curl request? It is just sometimes in the documentation they call it accessToken and other times they call it apiToken so I don't know what the key should be in the data parametre.

Comment: i was just fixing your ajax call. I just checked inbox.app and the apiToken needs to be sent as the username.

Comment: Oh, I see... No, wait. I'm still getting the 401 unauthorised error and my code is exactly like your second example.